# Showing a button to the user based on the data entered in the TextFormField

Tags: flutter, dart

```
final TextEditingController _weight = TextEditingController();

 if (_weight.text.contains(RegExp(r'[0-9]')))
        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
            child: BMIButton(
              onpressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  PageTransition(
                      type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
                      child: BMIHeight(),
                      inheritTheme: true,
                      ctx: context),
                );
              },
            ))
```

I'm trying to show an OutlinedButton when the user enters some data into the textFormField. When I enter a value in the TextFormField and confirm, it doesn't show a button, but when I hot reload it, it sees that value and shows the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add listener and call setState to update ui

```dart
 late final TextEditingController _weight = TextEditingController()
    ..addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
```

And override the dispose method and depose this controller.

Comment: Glad to help, make sure to dispose it, just to be safe.

Comment: I want to ask one more thing. For example, the user continued to the next page, but then wanted to come to this page again. How can I show the TextFormField blank again to the user? How can I delete the first entered value after changing the page?

Comment: you can clear the text while push to the next route `_weight.clear()` or you can use `await Navigator.push(...);_weight.clear() `

Comment: So how can I call this value entered by the user globally from other files? For example, after the user has entered all the values, how can I calculate and show the values ​​under a page like "Results"?

Comment: Instead of global variable, I will suggest you to check  state-management solution like riverpod/bloc, you can use [ValueNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html) for small case, but state-management solution is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

This means you need just to update the state of your widget, first make sure this inside a `StatefulWidget`, then add a `SetState(() {})` on the end of that method:

```
if (_weight.text.contains(RegExp(r'[0-9]')))
        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
            child: BMIButton(
              onpressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  PageTransition(
                      type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
                      child: BMIHeight(),
                      inheritTheme: true,
                      ctx: context),
                );
              },
            ))
           //...
           setState(() {}) // add this
```

Answer (score 0):

`TextEditingController` is implementing `Listenable`. You can exploit that to build part of your UI conditionally.

Moreover, `TextEditingController` must be correctly initialized and disposed of. You can do that smoothly with [flutter_hooks](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_hooks).

You'd obtain this concise result:

```dart
class MyWidget extends HookWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textController = useTextEditingController();

    return Column(  // example, I'm not sure of what you've got there
      children: [
        TextField(controller: textController),  // Your Text Field
        ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: textController,
          builder: (context, value, child) {
            return value.text.contains(...)
                ? OutlinedButton(  // Your Button
                    onPressed: () {
                      // .. do stuff
                    },
                    child: const Text('I am ready to be pressed'),
                  )
                : const SizedBox.shrink();  // This is empty, but you can render whatever
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code that checks if the TextFormField is populated needs to be inside the build function of a stateful widget.
To trigger the state update, listen to changes on the TextFormField, inside the function set the state of some variable that you can check.
Add this to the initState method:

```
_weight.addListener(() {
    setState(() {
        _inputText = _weight.text; // Create this variable inside the state class
    });
});
```

And change your if statement as follows:

```
if (_inputText.contains(RegExp(r'[0-9]')))
```

---

### Method 2

You could also Wrap your Widget with a Visibility Widget:

```
Visibility(
    visible: RegExp(r'[0-9]').hasMatch(_inputText),
    child: [YOUR WIDGET],
)
```

This still needs the listener with the setState call.